# Geoplugin API Displaying incorrect results

Tags: php

I'm using Geoplugin to retrieve users' current location. Everything works fine except the data is wrong. My Country is *Oman* but the output is USA.

Note that, I'm not using VPN or Proxy.

Code:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}


$url = unserialize(file_get_contents_curl('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$orig_lat = $url["geoplugin_latitude"];
$orig_lon = $url["geoplugin_longitude"];

echo $orig_lat; 
echo $orig_lon;
```

I'm using also cUrl instead of file_get_contents because allow_url_fopen in off in the server.

Output:

41.877602
-87.627197

**EDIT:**
I figure out that I forget to write ip in the url.  http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=

Problem SOLVED :)

Answer (score 0):

Using your code returns real coordenates to my location.

Geoplugin uses MaxMind DB to get data, you can check this source.